# Setting RouteValueDictionary html attributes differently on first object in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a fairly large method which is returning Radio buttons based fundamentally on an enum.

```
foreach (var name in names) 
    {

    //other stuff

        var id = string.Format(
        "{0}_{1}_{2}",
        htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
        metaData.PropertyName,
        name
        );

        var attribs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) { { "id", id }, { "checked", true } }; //<- I want this to be true on first, false on everything after
        var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, attribs).ToHtmlString();
        var field = fields.Single(f => f.Name == name);

    //more stuff
    }
```

I am arranging my array `names` in a certain order before I drop into the loop, the order stipulates that the first radio button should be checked when finally rendered to my page, and this is what I'm struggling with as, it is checking each and every item in the `for each`, resulting in the last item to go through being the one left checked.

I have tried adding something like:

```
bool firstRadioButton = true;
```

...outside the loop however I am loosing the reference to `attribs` etc. when I start placing them inside `if statements` and I cant seem to declare them without their required parameters outside the `if statements`.

Can anyone suggest a way that I can only set checked to `true` for `attribs` on the first pass of the `foreach`?

Comment: Add the code with `bool firstRadioButton = true;` It's not clear what you are doing with that. You *could* set a bool before the loop and then toggle it in the loop (something like `if(firstRadioButton){ // set you attribute; firstRadioButton = false; }`. Alternatively, if you are adding these to a collection you could use something like `First` after the loop to grab the first item and change that one attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you were doing with `firstRadioButton`, but something like this should work:

```
bool firstRadioButton = true;
foreach (var name in names) 
{
    // ....
    RouteValueDictionary attribs = null;
    if (firstRadioButton) 
    {
        attribs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) { { "id", id }, { "checked", true } }; //<- I want this to be true on first, false on everything after
        firstRadioButton = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        attribs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) { { "id", id }};
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instead `foreach` loop `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
{
        var name = names[i];


        var id = string.Format(
        "{0}_{1}_{2}",
        htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
        metaData.PropertyName,
        name
        );

        var attribs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) { { "id", id }, { "checked", i == 0 ? true : false} }; 
        var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, attribs).ToHtmlString();
        var field = fields.Single(f => f.Name == name);
}
```

Or in `foreach` you can do

```
    bool isFirst = true;

    foreach (var name in names) 
    {

            var id = string.Format(
            "{0}_{1}_{2}",
            htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
            metaData.PropertyName,
            name
            );

            var attribs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) { { "id", id }, { "checked", isFirst} }; 
            var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, attribs).ToHtmlString();
            var field = fields.Single(f => f.Name == name);

            if(isFirst)
            {
               isFirst = false;                
            }
   }
```